useHistory did not refresh the page
I use useHistory to reload my page.
In App.js
enter image description here
In Login.js
enter image description here
After I click submit, it did got the url http://localhost:3000/home, but it did not reload the page. it still show the login page content.
Here is my Home.js

Also, I'm using "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"

How What is there in your "Home" component ? Problem would be in Home component itself . useHistory hook working correctly if it is navigating you the page you push.
In React, useHistory is actually not used to refresh the page directly. Instead, it's a hook provided by React Router for navigation purposes. You can use it to programmatically navigate to different routes within your React application.
If you want to refresh the page (i.e., reload the current route), you can achieve this by using window.location.reload().

if the useHistory do not refresh the page, how should we change the page content between two pages?

In React, the content of a page dynamically updates in response to changes in the application's state data. This can be achieved using either local state, where the state is managed within individual components, or global state management solutions like Redux, where the state is maintained across the entire application. By updating the state, whether it's through user interactions, API calls, or other events, React re-renders components affected by the state change, ensuring that the page content reflects the most up-to-date data.
